# VSCode: How to run a Jupyter notebook in a docker container, over a remote server?

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, ssh, jupyter-notebook, remote-server

I can use the docker extension, and right click 'attach shell' to a running container. However, my Jupyter notebooks is not running in that container.

I tried googling how to run a jupyter notebook in a docker container, but I didn't get any results.

If it makes a difference, I am trying to run my notebook in a docker container on a remote server (using VS Code remote ssh to log in)

Edit:

I also tried running

`!docker exec -ti {container name} bash`

In jupyter, but that cell just hangs. When I stop the cell, the notebook still does not run in the container.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Update 31.08.2022:**
The original approach now may cause Docker error:

```
standard_init_linux.go:228: exec user process caused: no such file or directory
```

Which is fixed if you're using system package instead of raw download from repo. In case of Ubuntu:

```
RUN apt-get install tini
```

the rest is the same:

```
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/tini
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/tini", "--"]
CMD ["jupyter", "notebook", "--port=8888", "--no-browser", "--ip=0.0.0.0", "--allow-root"]
```

---

Just came to the same problem. It appeared that you cannot run Jupyter from a container out of the box. But [this link](https://u.group/thinking/how-to-put-jupyter-notebooks-in-a-dockerfile/) helped me. Basically what you need is:

1. Add this to your dockerfile:

```
# Add Tini. Tini operates as a process subreaper for jupyter. This prevents kernel crashes.
ENV TINI_VERSION v0.6.0
ADD https://github.com/krallin/tini/releases/download/${TINI_VERSION}/tini /usr/bin/tini
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/tini
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/tini", "--"]
CMD ["jupyter", "notebook", "--port=8888", "--no-browser", "--ip=0.0.0.0", "--allow-root"]
```

This will start jupyter inside a container on port 8888. So don't forget to expose this port in your docker-compose or docker run.

This worked for me in my local docker. I can assume that for SSH docker you need to forward 8888 port during you SSH connection from remote to your local host.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible

Step1: ssh into your remote server

```
$ ssh username@server_ip_address
```

Step2: Run this in the remote server

Running docker with port assignment

Replace image:version with your docker image id

```
$ docker run --gpus all -it -p 8888:8888 image:version
```

Step3: Run this inside docker

Starting jupyter notebook

```
$ jupyter notebook --ip 0.0.0.0 --port 8888 --no-browser --allow-root
```

Step4: Run this in your local sytem

Port forwarding from remote server to local system

```
$ ssh -N -L 8888:localhost:8888 username@server_ip_address
```

Step 5:

Access the notebook through your desktop browser on http://localhost:8888 The notebook will prompt you for a token which was generated when you create the notebook which you will find from Step 3

https://medium.com/@vishnubraj/script-src-https-gist-github-com-vishnuexe-9b18a2b5d0e1eb281dfa4eb55e851cf8-js-script-d5f2e61b6ced